# PHP min value positions of an integer array as a result array

Tags: php, arrays, min

I'd like to know how I can get the minimum value of an array in PHP, but instead of just returning the first found min value, **all** min values should be returned as a result.

For example, if we have an array with the following content:

`[1,2,4,7,5,1,1,3,2]`

Then the result should output the positions of the min value (1) in an array:

`[0,5,6]`

Comment: How far have you got with your own efforts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.array-keys.php), if a search_value is specified (the second param), then only the keys for that value are returned.

It's perfect for this use.

Whereas array_search will only return one key for a matching value/needle.

```
<?php

$items  = [1,2,4,7,5,1,1,3,2];
$min     = min($items);
$min_keys = array_keys($items, $min);

print_r($min_keys);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
)
```

Comment: In my mind array_keys is the way to do an array search, but you probably wouldn't pick it from name alone.

Comment: I knew there must be a clever and simple way of solving this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
<?php 

$array = [1,2,4,7,5,1,1,3,2];
$minNumber = min($array);
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  if ($v == $minNumber) {
     $result[] = $k;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
[0,5,6]
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match the output of your var_dump, but other than that, fine solution.

Comment: @Progrock :D It's not fine, yours is much better :)